# Latex Log too big (>2MB)

Tags: logging

My log is getting VERY big.
This is a short except:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+uop on input line 7.
(c:/texlive/2012/../texmf-local/tex/latex/uop/t1uop.fd
File: t1uop.fd 2006/12/24 Fontinst v1.929 font definitions for T1/uop.
)
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
\vbox(491.21909+0.0)x373.44246, glue set 4.44821
.\pdfdest name{chapter*.3} xyz
.\glue(\topskip) 11.0
.\rule(0.0+0.0)x*
.\penalty 10000
.\glue 50.0
.\glue 0.0
.\glue 0.0
.\glue 0.0
.\glue(\parskip) 14.5521 plus 1.45529
.\glue(\baselineskip) 9.63017
.\hbox(22.47005+9.63016)x373.44246, glue set 287.8553fil
..\glue(\leftskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
..\rule(22.47005+9.63016)x0.0
..\T1/uop/m/n/24.88 V
..\kern-1.56744
..\T1/uop/m/n/24.88 o
..\T1/uop/m/n/24.88 r
..\kern0.64687
..\T1/uop/m/n/24.88 w
..\kern-0.77129
..\T1/uop/m/n/24.88 o
..\T1/uop/m/n/24.88 r
..\kern0.59712
..\T1/uop/m/n/24.88 t
..\kern 0.0
..\rule(22.47005+9.63016)x0.0
..\penalty 10000
..\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0
..\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
.\penalty 10000
.\glue 0.0
.\glue 0.0
.\glue 40.0
.\glue 0.0
.\mark{{\protect \foreignlanguage {ngerman}{\protect \bbl@restore@actives Vo\ET
C.}
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parskip) 14.5521 plus 1.45529
.\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
.\hbox(7.9223+3.09885)x373.44246, glue set 0.48692
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) D
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) i
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) e
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) s
..\glue 3.18645 plus 1.91624 minus 0.7665
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) h
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) i
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) e
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) r
..\glue 3.18645 plus 1.91624 minus 0.7665
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) i
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) s
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) t
..\glue 3.18645 plus 1.91624 minus 0.7665
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) e
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) i
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) n
..\glue 3.18645 plus 1.91624 minus 0.7665
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) B
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) l
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) i
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) n
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) d
..\discretionary
...\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) -
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) t
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) e
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) x
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) t
..\glue 3.18645 plus 1.91624 minus 0.7665
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) z
..\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 (+20) u
```

You can read my text in vertical direction at the end of each line (in german).
Latex does this for all my text!

Does anyone know where this comes from?

Thanks for your help!
It's really appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: `\showoutput` would be my guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have said latex to log about everything it does (when decomposing what you have written as a series of boxes) using something like :

```
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
```

Maybe you should try adding something like this in the preamble of the document :

```
\showboxdepth=0
\showboxbreadth=0
```

This would normally tell it to stop that.

Comment: That was exactely the problem! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: No problem @Hans, I'm happy to have been able to help. 
In order to aknowledge this, please upvote my answer (click on the upwards arrow newt to it) and accept it (click on the tickmark below the arrows). ;-)
See [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work] for more on this topic.